# findChessboardCorners() failed to detect corners in back lighting condition

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a chessboard pattern placed on a window, and I am capturing image against the light - shooting from indoor to outdoor. The OpenCV `findChessboardCorners()` command failed to detect the chessboard.

First, I tried to capture image in controlled environment, and the command detect chessboard pattern just fine.

Second, I tried to use flags: `CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE` and `CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH`. Both flags didn't work in my case.

Then I tried using equalizing histogram, still it won't work.

I was hoping to find a way to tune the `findChessboardCorners()` to detect chessboard patterns in various environment conditions. Currently it wouldn't detect in back lighting condition.

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Can you use a grid of circles instead? I have found that cv.findCirclesGrid() is much more robust than cv.findChessboardCorners().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I currently have a very robust large format chessboard to get sub-millimeter accuracy. I would have used circle board if I have the equivalent hardware.